# Cloudflare redirect subdomain to URL

Tags: redirect, cloudflare

I would like to redirect one of my subdomains to an outside URL. Example: my `xyz.example.com` to `outsideurl.net`. Is it possible with use of `Cloudflare` services? I have tried to use `Page Rules` with help of this [tutorial](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-), but it seems this tutorial is for another purposes maybe.

Answer (score 32):

It won't work if you simply create a Page Rule -- you need to add a DNS record as well.

In your case, you can add a CNAME for `xyz` which directs to `@`, then set up a Page Rule to forward `xyz.example.com` to `outsideurl.net`.

From the [FAQ](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172356-Why-isn-t-a-Page-Rule-working-):

> The number one reason that a Page Rule isn't working, such as URL forwarding, is that the Page Rule you created is on a record that is not proxied by Cloudflare in your DNS settings.
>
> Example: You have a Page Rule that redirects a subdomain (subdomain.yoursitename.com) back to your root domain (yoursitename.com). If you do not have that record proxied in your DNS settings for the subdomain record (orange cloud), Cloudflare's proxy is not running over the record and a Page Rule will not work because it is going direct to your server.

Comment: I added a CNAME `@` but the redirect in page rule takes me to the root of the url and not deep into the page.